# Bootstrap container and span width problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and working on a site with it.

My challenge it to justify `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.responsive.min.css`

I got these files from bootswatch and from some free templates and the problem is the width of the site.

in `bootstrap.min.css`

```
.container {width : 994px;}
```

but in `bootstrap.responsive.min.css`

```
.container {width : 1170px} // which is too big, and i dont like it.
```

However, other objects are derived from .container such as `.span*`. So these files are not consistent with each other.

What i did was replacing the places of these css files in my app and it worked but not sure, if i did correct thing.

can you advice?

Comment: Are you familiar with LESS or SASS?

Comment: no i am not. i just got these files from bootswatch

Comment: Might be worth reading up. You can customize a lot of the bootstrap settings in variables.less. You can also try customizing your bootstrap download on their site: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: I recommend moving away from a fixed layout to use a fluid one instead. Wrap all content in div with max-width property and use .container-fluid. Inside use .row-fluid and normal .span*. If you prefer a fixed layout you can always override the .container width in your own stylesheet.